# Segmentation fault error

Tags: c, matlab, segmentation-fault, mex

I'm trying to write a MATLAB/mex code for a RLS filter for practicing my C, and of course for speeding up the code once I manage to get this going. However, I get a segmentation fault error when trying to run the following code with inputs.

```
#include <math.h>
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{       
    /* Macros for input data */
    #define xData prhs[0] /* Input signal to filter */
    #define dData prhs[1] /* Desired output signal */
    #define deltaData prhs[2] /* For initializing covariance matrix */
    #define lambdaData prhs[3] /* Forgetting factor */
    #define MData prhs[4] /* Filter order */

    /* Macros for output data */
    #define wData plhs[0] /* Final filter coefficients */
    #define yData plhs[1] /* Filter output signal vector */
    #define eData plhs[2] /* Error vector */
    #define WData plhs[3] /* Filter coefficients matrix */

    /* Variables */
    mxArray *xT, *P, *q, *k; /* Temp arrays */
    double *xr, *xi, *dr, *di, delta, lambda;
    double *Pr, *Pi, *qr, *qi, *kr, *ki, *xTr, *xTi, den;
    double *wr, *wi, *yr, *yi, *er, *ei, *Wr, *Wi;
    int M, Mx, Md, Nx, Nd, m, n, m1, m2, nT, l;

    /* Get pointers to input data */
    xr = mxGetPr(xData); /* Real */
    xi = mxGetPi(xData); /* Imag */
    dr = mxGetPr(dData); /* Real */
    di = mxGetPi(dData); /* Imag */
    delta = mxGetScalar(deltaData);
    lambda = mxGetScalar(lambdaData);
    M = (int)mxGetScalar(MData);

    /* Get dimensions of input data */
    Mx = mxGetM(xData); /* Number of rows in x */
    Nx = mxGetN(xData); /* Number of columns in x */
    Md = mxGetM(dData); /* Number of rows in d */
    Nd = mxGetN(dData); /* Number of columns in d */

    /* Temporary vector - size M-by-1 */
    xT = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    xTr = mxGetPr(xT); /* Real */
    xTi = mxGetPi(xT); /* Imag */

    /* Covariance matrix - size M-by-M */
    P = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, M, mxCOMPLEX);
    Pr = mxGetPr(P); /* Real */
    Pi = mxGetPi(P); /* Imag */

    /* Temporary vector for computing gain vector - size M-by-1 */
    q = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    qr = mxGetPr(q); /* Real */
    qi = mxGetPi(q); /* Imag */

    /* Gain vector - size M-by-1 */
    k = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    kr = mxGetPr(k); /* Real */
    ki = mxGetPi(k); /* Imag */

    /* Create output vector - size Mx-by-1 */
    yData = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(Mx, 1, mxCOMPLEX); 
    yr = mxGetPr(yData); /* Real */
    yi = mxGetPi(yData); /* Imag */

    /* Create error vector - size Mx-by-1 */
    eData = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(Mx, 1, mxCOMPLEX); 
    er = mxGetPr(eData); /* Real */
    ei = mxGetPi(eData); /* Imag */

    /* Create coeff. vector - size M-by-1 */
    wData = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, 1, mxCOMPLEX); 
    wr = mxGetPr(wData); /* Real */
    wi = mxGetPi(wData); /* Imag */

    /* Create coeff. matrix - size M-by-Mx */
    WData = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, Mx, mxCOMPLEX); 
    Wr = mxGetPr(WData); /* Real */
    Wi = mxGetPi(WData); /* Imag */

    m2 = 0;
    /* Initialize covariance matrix */
    for(m1 = 0; m1 < M; m1++, m2++)
    {
        Pr[m1*M+m2] = (1/delta); /* diag(P) = (1/delta) */
        Pi[m1*M+m2] = (1/delta); /* diag(P) = (1/delta) */
    }

    for(n = 0; n < Mx; n++)
    {
        /* Compute xT_m = [x[n] x[n-1] .... x[n-(M-1)]] */
        for(m = 0; m < M; m++)
        {/* Assume zeros outside available data and zero-fill*/
            if(n < (M-1)) 
            {
                nT = n;
                for(l = 0; l < M; l++)
                {
                     xTr[l] = xr[nT]; /* Real */
                     xTi[l] = xi[nT]; /* Imag */
                     if(nT == 0)
                         break;
                     else
                         nT--;
                 }
            } /* Data available for all lags */
            else 
            {   
                 xTr[m] = xr[n-m]; /* Real */
                 xTi[m] = xi[n-m]; /* Imag */
            }
            /* Set to zero prior to filling for computing gain vector */
            qr[m] = 0; /* Real */
            qi[m] = 0; /* Imag */
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Atm I've cut out a great amount of the code as I've managed to find out where the error comes from; if I comment out the following parts in the code below it runs (but then of no use for me). I've tried to print out the indices used in the arrays to see if one of them turns negative, but no luck there. So I really can't find the error. Most likely something silly, but I just can't find out what the error is. I also use the same code snippet below in another function (for a LMS filter), and there it works as it should. The main difference between the two functions is the amount of temporary arrays required for processing. So the big question is: does anyone see any obvious mistake in the code which should lead to a seg. fault? (Otherwise I know that the code is probably not as good as it can, but that will come with time when I've written some more C I assume).

```
for(m = 0; m < M; m++)
{/* Assume zeros outside available data and zero-fill*/
    if(n < (M-1)) 
    {
        nT = n;
        for(l = 0; l < M; l++)
        {
            // xTr[l] = xr[nT]; /* Real */
            // xTi[l] = xi[nT]; /* Imag */
            if(nT == 0)
                break;
            else
                nT--;
            }
    } /* Data available for all lags */
    else 
    {   
            // xTr[m] = xr[n-m]; /* Real */
            // xTi[m] = xi[n-m]; /* Imag */
    }
    /* Set to zero prior to filling for computing gain vector */
    qr[m] = 0; /* Real */
    qi[m] = 0; /* Imag */
}
```

Comment: wow you have a lot of pointers there with macros as well, could be anywhere. What does the debugger say?

Comment: I am surprised that printing out the indexes does not show the error, I would have though that you have got an index < 0 or > than the max size of your arrays.

Comment: What dimensions are you working with? Is it possible that you run out of memory (`mxCreateDoubleMatrix` returns `NULL`) ? What happens if you comment the unused arrays (k, yData, eData, wData, WData)?

Comment: @king_nak: Memory shouldn't be any problem. In the code, Mx is typically between 1e3 to 1e5, whereas M is in the range 2 to 32 for what I use the filtering for.

But it turned out the main error was in the MATLAB script calling the mex function, which I totally forgot about once I start focusing looking for negative indices. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a lot of pointers, so any of them can be causing the segmentation fault.

From the debbuging you did, most likely the problem is in one the the following pointers:

xTr, xTi, xr or xi;

All of them are initialized with the function mxGetPr() or mxGetPi(). Without knowing what it does, it is impossible to be sure. Are you sure it returns a pointer to an array? are you sure both arrays have at least m elements?

It quite a complex structure you have there, so it is a complicated job to fully analise all the pointers to find the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your comment about the pointers made check everything once again, and indeed it was a stupid stupid mistake.

I've written the code so I can process complex-valued data, but for some stupid reason the data I've been passing from MATLAB to the mex gateway was real-valued (probably forgotten to change from some other testing with other functions) making the pointers pointing to the imaginary part of the data cause seg.faults.

So note to self is to use a check for datatype (real/complex) at the beginning of all functions in order to avoid such silly mistakes.:)

Comment: just curious... shouldn't algorithms for complex numbers work for real numbers too, as `R` is a subset of `C`?

Comment: Indeed they should, with minor changes for this case though (i.e. less variables needed for real data, as only one pointer is required for arrays). This is probably a result of how the mex API is made.